# Jolt Transform an Array Objects and Move Some Fields to Nested Array

Tags: json, transactions, jolt

I want to transform the following array of `diagnoses` and move all the fields except `sequence` to a nested `coding` array.

**JSON Input**

```json
{
  "diagnoses": [
    {
      "version": "20230607",
      "code": "A100",
      "display": "Diagnosis 1",
      "sequence": 1
    },
    {
      "version": "20230607",
      "code": "B100",
      "display": "Diagnosis 2",
      "sequence": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

**Desired Output**

```json
{
  "diagnoses": [
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "version": "20230607",
          "code": "A100",
          "display": "Diagnosis 1"
        }
      ],
      "sequence": 1
    },
    {
      "coding": [
        {
          "version": "20230607",
          "code": "B100",
          "display": "Diagnosis 2"
        }
      ],
      "sequence": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

---

I can transform a single `diagnoses` object as expected but can't correctly transpose the array. Here's an example of the input and spec for transforming a single `diagnoses` object.

**JSON Input (single object)**

```json
{
  "version": "20230607",
  "code": "A100",
  "display": "Diagnosis 1",
  "sequence": 1
}
```

**Jolt Spec**

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sequence": "&",
      "*": "coding[0].&"
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore that you have 2 different types of input and write your own Jolt spec. Because you have your array input in the `sequence` key, or otherwise you have them in the root object.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "diagnoses": {
        "*": {
          "*": "&2[&1].coding[0].&",
          "sequence": "&2[&1].&"
        }
      },
      "*": "coding[0].&",
      "sequence": "&"
    }
  }
]
```